# Software/library to generate Ising models for random $k$-sat problems

Tags: optimization, np-complete, np-hard, satisfiability, constraint-satisfaction

Could someone point me to a software/library which lets one to generate the Ising model/spin model for random $k$-sat problems or $k$-sat problem of a given structure?

I understand that it will be based on the following mapping from Chapter 3 of Saitta et. al. and the coefficients will be based on a quenched disordered spin system.

[image]

I am happy to write one but not interested to reinvent the wheel if it already exists. TIA